# Fixed route for a network interface with two IP aliases

Tags: networking, tcp, cluster, windows-server-2016, route

On a Windows 2016 Server, I need to set a custom route, so that connections to a specific destination ip address always use a specific source ip. But while the `route add` command allows me to specify the interface, it does not allow me to specify a source IP.

The server has one network interface with multiple IP addresses, e.g. both `10.0.0.10` and `10.0.0.20` are bound to this network interface, and the server is reachable by either IP:

```
c:>ipconfig
Ethernet adapter myAdapter:
  IPv4 Address. . . . . : 10.0.0.10
  Subnet Mask . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  IPv4 Address. . . . . : 10.0.0.20
  Subnet Mask . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway . . . : 10.0.0.1
```

By default, all outgoing connections use `10.0.0.10` as the source IP.

I need a route, so that all connections to one specific remote address (`10.123.123.123`) always come from the second local ip (`10.0.0.20`), because the device at `10.123.123.123` is configured to only accept connections from `10.0.0.20`, not from `10.0.0.10`:

```
c:>telnet 10.123.123.123 111
   This tcp connection should use 10.0.0.20 as the origin IP
```

I can add a route with

```
route ADD 10.123.123.123 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.0.0.1 METRIC 1 IF 1
```

However this does not change the source IP address `10.0.0.20`. Outgoing connections still originate from the IP `10.0.0.10`.

How can I specify which IP address the route should use, when both IPs have the same interface number?

Only connections to the IP `10.123.123.123` should be affected by this route.
All other connections should continue to use the origin IP `10.0.0.10`.

Since this is a complicated legacy system mess, I am looking for a solution with minimal risk of affecting other connections, and without changes to existing software.

Therefore I would prefer not to change the global metrics for this interface, or split up the interfaces, if at all possible. A specific route affecting only ip `10.123.123.123` would be ideal.

Comment: Routes are generally only refer to the destination address and gateway, not the source address. You would need to perform `Network address translation (NAT)` to make the desired configuration work. In particular, you want to utilize `SNAT` where the source address of an IP packet is being replaced. Windows server pretends to be capable of `NAT` (to be activated via Role->Remote Access->Routing), but it cannot perform `SNAT` in the way you want it.